# Separating a GUID from text in an Excel cell into its own column

Tags: string, excel, search, replace, guid

I have some text data in an Excel sheet. One column has a GUID in it and some other text in front of the GUID. I want to get the GUID into a separate column. My thought was to do a search and replace and put a comma before the GUID, then export as CSV and re-import getting the GUID into its own column. How would I go about separating the GUID from the cell data and getting it into its own column next to the text data?

Example data in the cell: "this is item_number 10 c9c8a159-98d6-5df9-8566-7d107893e526"

Comment: There's a [superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/637448/parse-data-in-excel-space-delimited-right-to-left) about parsing text right-to-left that might be helpful. You could use that tip, and then do a Text to Columns on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with formulas

```
First part:  =LEFT(A1,-1+FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))

GUID:  =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

For the first part, we substitute a character that would not be used in normal text (CHAR(1)) for the last space in the string.  We then use the LEFT and FIND to return all the characters up to but not including that character.

You could use a similar technique for the GUID with the MID and FIND functions.  But I am showing a different technique for returning the last item in the string -- replace all the spaces with a lot of spaces; then use the RIGHT function with that number of spaces to return the portion containing only the last segment.  Then TRIM it to get rid of the extra spaces.  This method can be adapted to easily parse out each word.